# Extra height added to divs, but from where?

Tags: html, css

I have four ".thumbnail" objects (234 x 176) in a ".thumbHolder" container which should be flush with primary ".row" container.

However, the ".row" height is being rendered in my browsers (Chrome 31.0.1650.57m and Firefox 25) with an additional 4 pixels of height.  The ".row" should be height:176px but is being rendered at 181px.  CSS Should allow me to NOT need to specify the height, correct?  I have a dynamic amount of content and don't wish to run a jQuery.css("height") update to remove these extra four pixels.

Applying font-size:0 to my CSS' .row class resolves the issue.  But there's no actual floating text, thus the solution feels hacky.  Another solution was to change the DOCTYPE from "html" to `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` but ... well, shouldn't Chrome support simple, simple, simple html elements as HTML5 doctypes?

I have made the ".row" background an extra 20 pixels wide so, in the event the extra height is resolved, I can still see the pink ".row" background color and confirm the height is what I wish it to be.

MY HTML (I've also tried making all the divs inline without any format breaks):

```
<body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="thumbHolder">
                <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://media.edge-online.com/wp-content/uploads/edgeonline/2012/12/Batman-Arkham-City.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://media.edge-online.com/wp-content/uploads/edgeonline/2012/12/Batman-Arkham-City.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://media.edge-online.com/wp-content/uploads/edgeonline/2012/12/Batman-Arkham-City.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://media.edge-online.com/wp-content/uploads/edgeonline/2012/12/Batman-Arkham-City.jpg"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

MY CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #94b7d2;
}

.row {
    width:956px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #f00fff;
}

.thumbHolder {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.thumbnail {
    width: 234px;
    height: 176px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

.thumbnail img{
    width:234px;
    height:176px;
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle for ya: http://jsfiddle.net/8gWWx/

What the heck?  This is the simplest thing one should be able to do with liquid sizing, right?  There's nothing complicated.  I've had my CSS and HTML validated and aside from missing  attributes, it's solid.

Cheers for any solutions ... I've stumped my coworkers with this one!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`.thumbHolder` is `inline-block`, and therefore has space for character descenders. Set it to `block` and be happy.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8gWWx/4/

Comment: A `div` is `block` by default. No need to add `display:block` ;)

Comment: This removes the background coloring and the pink overflow on the right.  Setting to block appears to set the width/height of .thumbHolder to 0,0.  Unless something else is going on, because I no longer see that div.

Answer (score 0):

Set `.thumbHolder` to `display: block;` not `inline`. Otherwise hide the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces (includes line-breaks and tabs):

```
... </div><div...
```

Or negate the margin in your css:

```
.thumbnail {
    width: 234px;
    height: 176px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

More info: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

Over time and so much failing, I found out JavaScript-resizing *everything* `onLoad` and `onResize` (placed on the `<body>` tag) is the most cross-browser solution ever. Just put IDs on all of your images, form fields and text snippets, then make a JavaScript function like

```
function resize_elements () {
  var availalbe = window.innerHeight; 
  var wanted_font_size_main = (16/512) // you have to know your window/frame height/width);
  document.getElementById('your_moms_text1').style.fontSize = wanted_font_size_main; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set `line-height:0;` to the element, which's getting extra height